# Socket Programming with MFC

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, ipv6

Is there any support for `Ipv6` socket programming by `MFC`
so that we can connect to a server having `Ipv6` address using Microsoft foundation classes? [I have read this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/ipv6-guide-for-windows-sockets-applications-2)  but it is not much help to me.

Comment: thanks, Actually I have one MFC application working fine with ipv4 but I want to use Ipv6 in the same application Can this be possible ???

Answer (score 1):

The CAsyncSocket does support IPv6 sort of. There are several methods to do that:

- ConnectEx
- BindEx
- ReceiveFromEx
- SendToEx
- GetSockNameEx
- GetPeerNameEx

However, I'd suggest using Winsock 2 API directly.

Comment: thanks i didnt get ConnectEx method can you plz share me the link

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin there is no mention of `ConnectEx()` or `BindEx()` in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/casyncsocket-class) , but there are `Connect()` and `Bind()` overloads that take a `SOCKADDR*` as input. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin I have used ConnectEx() for connection for ipv6 method I am getting this error code 10047 "Address family not supported by protocol family" plz confirm this function works or not for ipv6

Comment: Please provide minimal example. Have you initialized winsock?

Comment: I have initialized winsock but still this error 10047 :-"An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. All sockets are created with an associated address family (that is, AF_INET for Internet Protocols) and a generic protocol type (that is, SOCK_STREAM)" this mean AF_INET6 cannot be used

Comment: Take a look at filezilla socket implementation. It uses the same interface as CAsyncSocket. https://github.com/baloonwj/filezilla/tree/master/filezillaserverinterface

Comment: I could not help you as you have not provided anything even minimal example. The way you initialize socket layer, create/connect, etc

Comment: @Andrew Komiagin i have posted the code for client side

Answer (score 0):

The code here works for me:

```
LPCTSTR lpszHost = L"::1"; 
CSocket socket; 
int nPort = 1234;
ADDRINFOT addrInfo;
memset( &addrInfo, 0, sizeof( addrInfo ) );
addrInfo.ai_family = AF_INET6;
addrInfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if ( socket.CreateEx( &addrInfo ) )
{
    struct sockaddr_in6 addr;
    memset( (LPVOID)&addr, 0, sizeof( addr ) );
    addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    addr.sin6_port = htons( nPort );
    InetPtonW( AF_INET6, lpszHost, &addr.sin6_addr );
#ifdef MY_SOCKET_SERVER
// Server
    BOOL bSuccess = socket.Bind( reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>(&addr), sizeof(sockaddr_in6) );
#else 
// Client
    BOOL bSuccess = socket.Connect( reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>(&addr), sizeof(sockaddr_in6) );        
#endif
}
```